# How can I directly get value from std::istream to std::atmoic?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Getting a value from `std::istream` is quite easy.

```
double d;
std::cin >> d;
```

However, I found extracting a value from `std::istream` to `std::atomic<double>` was not available. Following code does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main(){
  std::atomic<double> d;
  std::cin >> d;  // can not compile

  return 0;
}
```

Here's my attempt using temporary variable, but I want to ask if there's a better way to directly assign value **without any temporary variable** like tmp in the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main(){
  double tmp;
  std::cin >> tmp;

  std::atomic<double> d = tmp;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short of writing a separate function that uses a temporary internally, I don't believe there would be a way. Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid a temporary here anyway?

Comment: @Human-Compiler Just wondering if there's a possible way which I didn't know. If temporary variable is inevitable in this case, I would be using it.

Comment: The formatted extraction operator must have a reference it can update as it reads through characters. If you wanted to directly reference the `std::atomic` value, that would require multiple sequential accesses to the variable. I'm not a performance expert, but I predict that would be not great. To avoid thrashing, any implementation will have to write to a temporary. I assume there's no standard library way of doing this because the library can't know what atomic access method you'll want to use.

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer to avoid a temporary variable? The way you've written it, with the temporary variable, is perfectly fine. What do you seek to gain from avoiding it?

Comment: @BrianBi There is no specific reason to avoid. I was wondering if there is a better way without temporary just like when using non-atomic primitive types, but I found, as many commented, using temporary variable is usual way.

Comment: @JohnPark But I fail to see why you describe the hypothetical "way without temporary" as being "better" in the first place. Certainly there are reasons why one might wish to avoid it, *e.g.*, to avoid having to clutter the code. Or perhaps you are on an embedded platform where every byte counts (though in that case I severely doubt you would be using iostreams). In any case, the potential workarounds differ depending on your ultimate objective.

Comment: @BrianBi "to avoid having to clutter the code..." Yes, I don't want to declare a variable that might not be needed. However, I found there's no secret option, and I would use a temporary variable since it seems  there's no way to assign value to `std::atomic` directly from `std::istream`. I posted this question because I thought there might be a way to associate them that I didn't know.

Comment: If the objective is to not clutter the code with an extra temporary variable, then write a function that makes the temporary variable (and takes the `std::atomic<double>` by reference) and just call the function.